# Rear wheel won’t do a full rotation before locking

Tags: honda, motorcycle, troubleshooting, cb750

I have 1979 cb750k. This is a project and I haven’t started it yet. I picked it up rolled it around a bit then went to wash it. After washing it the rear wheel has become locked at a certain point and will only roll one rotation and lock. (Can then roll backward til locked i.e. just rocking the distances of a rotation). Would this be the brake shoes on the rear drum? I will
Be taking the chain off but am hoping this isn’t at the front sprocket? Any other suggestions?

Comment: Is the transmission in nuetral?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Yes. When I’m neutral I get fairly more rotation. When In gear it won’t move as normal